# Windows 10: How do I install an input method without installing the associated language pack?

Tags: windows-10, language, input-languages, language-pack

I'm running Windows 10 Pro, version 1803.

It used to be that when I install a new input method, I would be given the choice whether to install the associated language pack along with the input method.

I used to have English (default), French and Japanese input methods. I am trying to install the Chinese input method, but I have no option to install it without installing the associated language pack.

With the other languages, I have a "language pack available" message. With the new input language I have instead a "language pack installed" message without the possibility to uninstall the language pack while keeping the input method.

The problem is that the newly-installed input languages override the display language no matter what I set.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the previously existing input methods and I have the same problem. The language pack would be installed along with the input method. The French language is overriding the default (English) display language no matter the setting.

Is there a way to install input methods without installing the associated language pack?

EDIT: I do not have the options as described in the following answers. They correspond to an older version of Windows 10. See my screenshot:

[image: Install language features]

The language pack is installed even if I do not select any of these options:

[image: Installed languages]

Comment: My answer and screenshots correspond to the latest version of Windows 10 - Version 1809. Your version is older. Maybe 1803?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained well in this guide: [How to add, change and remove keyboard input languages in Windows 10](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/add-change-remove-keyboard-input-language-windows-10).
What you need to remember is this:

- You go through the procedure as if you are installing a display language.
- After you select the language you desire, look carefully at all the options that are given to you. Make sure that you uncheck the option *"Install language pack and set as my Windows display language"*. Also, uncheck other features you do not want, like Speech or maybe Handwriting. All you need is *Basic Typing*.
  [image]
  Then you install only the keyboard input language, and not the display language.

Comment: Please note if you want to promote or recommend your own product/blog, there are some [guidelines in place](https://superuser.com/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Could you please [edit] to explicitly state your affiliation? Thanks. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)

Comment: @corporate geek I have updated my question in consequence.

Comment: The checkbox about the language pack is disabled.

Answer (score -1):

In Settings, go to Time & Language, and click Language. Then under Preferred Languages, click on Add a Preferred Language. After that, select Chinese and click on next, after which you are able to select which components you want to add (some can't be removed, such as supplemental fonts etc.)

[image: Check this screenshot for more info]

As you can see, you can deselect the option to download the display language. Also, to fully delete existing language packs and input languages, I would suggest going to Settings --> Apps & Features --> Manage optional features, where you can delete them fully.

Comment: I have updated my question in consequence.